# How do I show warnings when loading data created from mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I've got a large .sql file with large insert into ... values ... statements.  Many of these statements are generating warnings during execution.  How can I get mysql to print the warnings?

If it hit control-C then the import stops and I'm dropped back to the OS command line.

Here is sample output from running the SQL:

```
Query OK, 9827 rows affected, 5403 warnings (0.20 sec)
Records: 9827  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 5403

Query OK, 9859 rows affected, 5247 warnings (0.20 sec)
Records: 9859  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 5247
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should startup mysqld with [log-warnings](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings) (it should be on by default) and also the [max error count](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_error_count)

```
[mysqld]
log-warnings
max-error-count=9999999999
```

You may have to start the mysql client with

```
SET SQL_WARNINGS = 1;
```

This is not mysqld setting, it's a mysql client session setting.

You may want to add show-warnings to mysql client session

```
mysql -u... -p -hlocalhost --show-warnings
```

Comment: That option does not print these warnings to the server's error log.

Comment: The first suggestion should put warnings in the error log.

Comment: adding --show-warnings to the mysql client worked like a charm, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With the *mysql* client you can also do:

```
mysql> tee import.log
mysql> source .\test.sql
```

then view the *import.log* file created in the current directory.